# Is it possible to use clamp() inside of scale() in CSS?

Tags: html, css, scale, clamp

Pretty simple question. Just need to know if you can use clamp() inside of scale()? Like this:

```
.element {
   scale(clamp(100px, 10%, 300px));
}
```

This does not work. How can i do this?

Comment: scale as a property is not supported on many browsers at the moment. What browser are you using? Have you tried transform: scale()? And what error are you seeing when you inspect the applied CSS?

Comment: ..for example, what would scaling with a factor of 100px actually mean? Read up about scale and how to use it e.g. on MDN.

Comment: no it's not possible

Comment: @AHaworth I am using chrome, and there is no error, It just doesn't scale as expected. I also am doing this to have the element be responsive.

Comment: I can't understand why Chrome isn't giving you some warning. Are you sure? Using Chrome and your CSS I get a yellow triangle by the style and Unknown Property. If I change to a transform I get Invalid property value. Anyway, given 100px, for example, does not make sense as a scale parameter please could you describe what you want to happen. How much do you want it to scale in different circumstances?

Comment: @AHaworth I just want to scale responsively.

Comment: I don't know what that means. If you want say an element to scale to the width of the viewport set its width in vw units. If you want an element to scale to the width of its containing element set its width in % units. Nothing to do with transform: scale.

Comment: So there is no way to scale responsively using ```transform: scale()``` or ```scale()```? Cuz that was another thing i wanted to find out

Comment: Perhaps if you could give two examples of viewport dimensions and an element you want to scale responsively I'd understand better what you mean. Are you for example stuck with some fixed px dimensions for an element which you are happy with at one screen size and need to change for another?

Comment: You can scale using rem instead, where you set different values of the font size depending if it's mobile or desktop. If it's just height/width that you need to scale, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```css
.element {
   scale(clamp(100px, 10%, 300px));
}
```

is invalid in 2 ways. First of all there is no `scale()` what you mean is `transform: scale()`. Second: `scale()` works with number/float only (e.g. 0.5, 1, 2). So no, `clamp()` is not possible.

Edit:

What you could do is to use a css variable and media queries:

```css
#box {
  --scale: 3;
  
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  transform: scale(var(--scale));
} 

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #box {
    --scale: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 512px) {
  #box {
    --scale: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Edit:

Well you could actually make the `scale()` responsive by manipulating a css variable e.g. `--scale` via js and using the computed font-size for `clamp()`.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    scaleBox();
}, true);

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    scaleBox();
}, true);

function scaleBox() {
  const box = document.querySelector('#box');
  
  // Box font size in px.
  const boxFontSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(box).fontSize);
  
  // Document font size in px.
  const documentFontSize = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
  
  // Calculated scale factor.
  const scaleFactor = boxFontSize / documentFontSize;
  
  // Update the scale factor variable.
  box.style.setProperty('--scale', scaleFactor);
  
  console.log(`font-size: ${boxFontSize}px;`, `--scale: ${scaleFactor};`);
}
```

```css
#box {
  --scale: 1;
  
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  font-size: clamp(.5rem, 10vmax, 300px);
  transform: scale(var(--scale));
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: scale as a property does exist but is currently only supported in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: You're right, but then its not "scale()" but "scale:".